# RESTful servive : Unable to return array of object using json

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest

This sample was extracted from one of the many samples found via Google.
The application returns 3 objects but all attributes are NULL.

The following is the Controller Object.

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/employees")
public class EmployeeController 
{
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    @GetMapping(path="/", produces = "application/json")
    public Employees getEmployees() 
    {
        return employeeDao.getAllEmployees();
    }

    @PostMapping(path= "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) 
    {
        Integer id = employeeDao.getAllEmployees().getEmployeeList().size() + 1;
        employee.setId(id);

        employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                                    .path("/{id}")
                                    .buildAndExpand(employee.getId())
                                    .toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
}
```

Here is the Employees object which gets returned via the getEmployees call.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employees 
{
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        if(employeeList == null) {
            employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}
```

In case you need it, here is the DAO.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO 
{
    private static Employees list = new Employees();

    static
    {
        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employee(11, "Lokesh", "Gupta", "howtodoinjava@gmail.com"));
        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employee(22, "Alex", "Kolenchiskey", "abc@gmail.com"));
        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employee(33, "David", "Kameron", "titanic@gmail.com"));
    }

    public Employees getAllEmployees() 
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        list.getEmployeeList().add(employee);
    }
}
```

As requested, here is the Employee class.

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;

import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.ApplicationScope;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

//@ManagedBean
//@ApplicationScope
//@Data

public class Employee {


    public Employee() {

    }
    public Employee(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Setter  @Getter  private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    //Getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is the partial client code....

```
    private static void getEmployees() 
    {

        // HttpHeaders
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
        // Request to return JSON format
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("my_other_key", "my_other_value");

        // HttpEntity<String>: To get result as String.
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        // RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Send request with GET method, and Headers.
        ///This works but only prints IDs.        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        String result = response.getBody();
        System.out.println(result);

        HttpEntity<Employees> entity2 = new HttpEntity<Employees>(headers);
      ResponseEntity<Employees> eResponse = restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES, HttpMethod.GET, entity2, Employees.class);
      List <Employee> eList = eResponse.getBody().getEmployeeList();
      for (Employee e : eList)
      {
          System.out.println(e.toString());
      }
   }
```

From the above, the following call works and prints out the 3 IDs.

```
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    String result = response.getBody();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Once the IDs were returned, the next step was to print out all the attributes for each employee using the next set of calls.

```
  ResponseEntity<Employees> eResponse = restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Employees.class);
  List <Employee> eList = eResponse.getBody().getEmployeeList();
  for (Employee e : eList)
  {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
```

I placed a break point on the line doing the LIST call and verified the eResponse object has 3 items in the List BUT all 3 items show each of their associated attributes to be NULL.

Since I confirmed the call seems to be working since the IDs are returned in the first call, what command or setup is missing for the 2nd call to allow for the complete objects to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove super(); in the constructor. We use it to access the members of the super class. Your Employee class has no parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 3 important pieces changed to get this working.

1 - Server Side - nothing really changed with this procedure.

```
@GetMapping(path="/", produces = "application/json")
public Employees getEmployees() 
{
    return employeeDao.getAllEmployees();
}
```

2 - Client side - simplified it.

```
private static void getEmployees() 
{

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("my_other_key", "my_other_value");
    HttpEntity<Employee> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null,headers);
    ResponseEntity<String>result = restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
 }
```

3 - Server Side - this was the key to getting it working.

Originally the Employee.java looked like this.

```
@Setter  @Getter private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
```

Once i change to the following, it worked.

```
@Setter  @Getter private Integer id;
@Setter  @Getter private String firstName;
@Setter  @Getter private String lastName;
@Setter  @Getter private String email;
```

Still not 100% of what is really going on but it works.